# merge from svn to git, commit by commit

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

Our company has two repositories, svn repository(trunk) used for development of one product and git repository(master) used for deployment of several products(teams). Our team wants to merge from svn subdirectory "trunk/web" to git subdirectory "master/product-a/web-dev".

Those repositories have different source codes with a different tree structure, but two subdirectories we want to merge have almost same source codes inside. Also, they're not linked in any way, and we need to merge manually for now. Git repository is shared by other teams and we cannot build it from scratch(cannot make big changes that might stop daily development&deployment).

Is it possible to merge from svn subdirectory to git subdirectory, commit by commit, in specified revision rage automatically(by a few commands or a long program)? We need to merge commit by commit with commit comments, so that we can trace changes on git by redmine issue number used in svn.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: sounds like you need to take a look at git-svn so that you can keep git "in sync" with what's going on with svn. It's very flexible in terms of allowing you to set up what you want to track.... but it's very slow in general because of having to go revision by revision "a la svn".

Comment: Why aren't you simply using one of those for everything? Like Git, why not do everything in git?

Comment: The reason we have two repositories is, our git repository(larger than 5GB) includes several products developed by several teams, and is optimized for deployment, so it needs several modfications to run one product on local tomcat server. The svn repository is modified for development, and we use it to develop each team's product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by the following step:

1. Create diff patch for Git by SVN

   ```
   svn diff --git -r 12345 > /tmp/12345-fileName.txt
   ```
2. Modify paths in patch text file to resolve the path difference between SVN and Git
3. Apply patch on local Git repository

   ```
   cd /path/to/local/git/repository & git apply /tmp/12345-fileName.txt
   ```
4. Commit on Git

   ```
   git commit
   ```

I ran a Java program to generate and execute those commands, and repeated the steps above, revision by revision, to merge specific range of revisions from SVN to Git.

I understand this is not a good practice, but I had to solve the ongoing problem without a big change in version control systems. Thank you all for your advices.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible using `git svn`. Setup:

```
git svn clone svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com/trunk
cd trunk
git remote add origin git@github.com:example/develop.git
git fetch origin
```

This will set up a git repository with one branch named `git-svn` (svn trunk), and *another* branch named `master` (git develop).

Then to apply commits:

```
git checkout master
git svn fetch
git cherry-pick git-svn...git-svn~10
git push
```

...this will apply the last 10 commits on trunk and commit them to develop.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Is it possible to merge from svn subdirectory "trunk/web" to git subdirectory "master/product-a/web-dev"? Our svn repository is for one product only, but git repository includes several products.

Comment: Yes. I'm not too sure on the details, but it would look something like this: `git format-patch trunk/web/ && git am -3 --directory=master/product-a/web-dev/`. For info, see `man git-format-patch` and `man git-am`.

Comment: Thank you, I went with this solution. To speed up the very slow git svn clone, I restored only the last revisions: git svn clone -r12345:HEAD svn://...

Comment: Thank you. As my "git svn checkout" creates master branch, I had to rename it by "git branch -m master git-svn" before referring to origin.