# SVN commit automatically commit on github

Tags: git, github, svn

I want to do auto commit on github when i did commit on svn.

We have SVN and one repo for other project on github.
And i read many documentation about this.
commands like "git svn" and other.

For example i have project "myproject" on github git@git.example.com:directory/myproject.git

And i have directory on SVN like this: http://example.com/svn/project/_Trunk/myproject

i did clone on SVN and now i have project on SVN.

I don't know how to do auto commit, please help me.

Comment: Have you looked at this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922763/merge-from-svn-to-git-commit-by-commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge from svn to git, commit by commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922763/merge-from-svn-to-git-commit-by-commit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use hooks. I wrote [a note](http://uzsolt.hu/notes/svn/svn-mirror-github.html) about it some months ago (only hungarian).

**Preparation:**

```
cd /path/to/git/
git svn init -s http://svn.yourdomain.com/repos/project_name project_name
cd project_name
git svn fetch

git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECT
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

The `post-commit` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

# svn.yourdomain.com/repos/project_name/hooks/post-commit

cd /path/to/git/project_name
git svn rebase
git push origin master
```

If you commit to subversion repository, automatically will commit to github (without any plus work).